# adding a logfile to ffmpeg

Tags: php, logging, ffmpeg

ive been searching for a solution for some hours now, but I cant find a solution.

I want ffmpeg to give me a log file after converting is completed.

this is my code:

```
$convert = '/usr/bin/ffmpeg -i /var/www/html/videos/' . $fileNormal . '.mp4 -vn -sn -c:a mp3 -ab 192k /var/www/html/audio/' . $fileFixed . '.mp3 2> var/www/html/logs/' . $id . '.txt';

exec($convert);
```

same with

```
$convert = '/usr/bin/ffmpeg -i /var/www/html/videos/' . $fileNormal . '.mp4 -vn -sn -c:a mp3 -ab 192k /var/www/html/audio/' . $fileFixed . '.mp3 2> /var/www/html/logs/' . $id . '.txt';

exec($convert);
```

or

```
$convert = '/usr/bin/ffmpeg -i /var/www/html/videos/' . $fileNormal . '.mp4 -vn -sn -c:a mp3 -ab 192k /var/www/html/audio/' . $fileFixed . '.mp3 2> /logs/' . $id . '.txt';

exec($convert);
```

if I add anything at the end after mp3 it doesnt convert at all.

appreciate any help. thanks

Comment: Have you tried adding **-report** before the **-i**?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to log the screen output of the ffmpeg command, you can do this by redirecting the output to a log file. For example:

```
/usr/bin/ffmpeg -i /var/www/html/videos/' . $fileNormal . '.mp4 -vn -sn -c:a mp3 -ab 192k /var/www/html/audio/' . $fileFixed . '.mp3  > log_file_path.txt
```

Also see the man page for the ffmpeg command: https://linux.die.net/man/1/ffmpeg. It mentions loglevel and debug options which can be used to control the level of detail in the log data